# Problems with r2pmml

Tags: r, pmml

I recently installed package r2pmml and all its dependencies in `R`. However, when I'm trying to convert my gbm model object to pmml it throws this error:

```
r2pmml::r2pmml(model,"model.pmml")

Error in .jnew("org/jpmml/rexp/Main") : 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jpmml/rexp/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I'm a noob when it comes to java and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are using an outdated Java version, which [does not support Java 1.7 class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error) - please upgrade. The requirement for Java 1.7 is also stated in r2pmml's README file.

To debug your rJava configuration, please execute the following R script:

```
library("rJava")
.jinit()
props = .jcall("java/lang/System", "Ljava/util/Properties;", "getProperties")
out = .jfield("java/lang/System", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;", "out")
.jcall(props, "V", "list", out)
```

Please observe the value of the `java.home` property. It must point to a up-to-date Java installation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did update my java version to 1.8, but I still get the same error! --                                  $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Did you restart your R session also? It is likely that the rJava package still holds a reference to the old Java version.

Comment: I did restart both my mac and R. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also, how do I check which version rJava is referring to?

Comment: Is the system-level environment variable `JAVA_HOME` set? Will try to work out a R snippet that calls rJava to figure out the JVM in use.

Comment: Actually that's the part I'm not clear on. Do I need to set it in bash_profile? I'm not sure how to do it though. Could you please walk me through it?

Comment: Did you manage to locate the outdated Java installation that rJava chose over the new Java 1.8 one? You could try uninstalling that old version as the first step. I don't have experience working with Mac, so you need to do the googling yourself.

Comment: When I load rJava, the message I get tells me to install JRE 1.6 although it admits that this is below the version 1.8 that I have installed. The text of the popup message starts out:"To open “R” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime."