# obtain pmml representation of glm-type model produced by caret::train

Tags: r, r-caret, pmml

I am trying to produce PMML from a regression model trained in `caret` with `method='glm'`.  Example model:

```
library('caret')

data('GermanCredit')

set.seed(123)

train_rows <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p=0.6, list=FALSE)

train_x <- GermanCredit[train_rows, c('Age','ForeignWorker','Housing.Own',
                                      'Property.RealEstate','CreditHistory.Critical') ]
train_y <- as.integer( GermanCredit[train_rows, 'Class'] == 'Good' )

some_glm <- train( train_x, train_y, method='glm', family='binomial', 
                   trControl = trainControl(method='none') )

summary(some_glm$finalModel)
```

An unaccepted answer on this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428748/caret-model-random-forest-into-pmml-error) for `type='rf'` suggests that it is not possible to do using the matrix interface.

So I'm unable to get pmml using either the matrix or the formula syntax (which I'm pretty sure produce identical `finalModel`s anyway):

```
library('pmml')

pmml(some_glm$finalModel) 
# Error in if (model$call[[1]] == "glm") { : argument is of length zero

# Same problem if I try:
some_glm2 <- train( Class ~ Age + ForeignWorker + Housing.Own + 
                      Property.RealEstate + CreditHistory.Critical, 
                    data=GermanCredit[train_rows, ], family="binomial", 
                    method='glm',
                    trControl = trainControl(method='none') )
pmml(some_glm2$finalModel)
```

It **does** work in base glm with the formula interface:

```
some_glm_base <- glm(Class ~ Age + ForeignWorker + Housing.Own + 
                     Property.RealEstate + CreditHistory.Critical, 
                     data=GermanCredit[train_rows, ], family="binomial")
pmml(some_glm_base) # works
```

For interoperablity, I would like to continue to use `caret`.  Is there a way to convert `some_glm` produced in `caret` back to a format that `pmml()` will accept?  Or am I forced to use the `glm()` construction if I want pmml functionality?

Comment: Did you read the warning message? "Warning message:
In train.default(train_x, train_y, method = "glm", family = "binomial",  :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column."

Comment: After looking at the `pmml.glm` code and the structure of the `some_glm` object, this effort appears hopeless unles syou can find a function that maps the contents of the caret-glm object to the structure of a `stats::glm` object

Comment: @42- I saw the warning, but I'm not doing classification, just regression on a binary outcome.  (It's pretty much the same thing, but I just want a probability of the target class, not a class prediction.)

Comment: There is an r2pmml-package. I installed version 0.4.3 from source off GitHub and the required dependencies (but it has no help pages). I get an error with the attempt at conversion: `r2pmml(some_glm, "train-rf.pmml")
Error in .jnew("org/jpmml/rexp/Main") : 
  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jpmml/rexp/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`. I'm on a Mac (with uptodate Java) so users of other OS's may want to give it a shot.

Comment: The problem is that `caret::train()` converts "formula interface" invocations to "matrix interface" invocations before doing any work (probably for performance reasons).

Comment: @42- thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into `r2pmml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `model$call[[1]]`, the `pmml` function will work correctly.

So in your case you would want to:

```
library('pmml')

some_glm$finalModel$call[[1]] <- "glm"
pmml(some_glm$finalModel)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i got the following  
`Error in .pmmlDataDictionary(field, weights = weights, transformed = transforms) : 
  character class is not supported for features. Supported classes: numeric, logical, factor.`